# wget --spider: how to tell where broken links are coming from

Tags: wget

I use wget's built-in spider mode as a convenience sometimes to quickly check a local site for broken links. This morning I turned its attention to a production site that we'd just put major changes on, and it's coming up with 3 broken links, but it seems impossible to tell where they are! (It only says what they're linking to and there's no straightforward way of relating that alone back to a page.)

The options I'm currently using are `wget -r -nv --spider http://www.domain.com/ -o /path/to/log.txt`. Does anyone know of an option I'm overlooking, a way to read the output, or even a simple substitute for this command that will also let me know what file the links appear in (and ideally a line #)?

Comment: I get this while working on zedboard.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkNpQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkNpQ.png)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to watch the web server logs, in conjunction with the wget run. Look for the `404`'s in the log file and pull the `referrer` field. That will tell you the page that contains the broken link.

It should then just be a matter of examining that page for the offending link.

Comment: Good idea. I forgot I asked this on here, actually! What I ended up doing was using it in combination with grep on my local copy of the site (particularly using the -n option to get line numbers).

Comment: This is good for broken internal links, but not for links to external sites.

Answer (score 3):

A good way (not involving the webserver logs) is to use the `--debug` flag and grep for `^Referer:`

On the command line:

```
wget -r -nv --spider http://www.domain.com/ 2>&1 | egrep -A 1 '(^---response end---$|^--[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ERROR|^Referer:|^Remote file does not)'
```

You can do similar grepping on your log. Caveat: some wget are not compiled with the support for `--debug`

Comment: Or place all links inside text file and use `-i` switch to check that. `wget -r -nv --spider -i linkfile 2>&1 | egrep -A 1 '(^---response end---$|^--[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ERROR|^Referer:|^Remote file does not)'
`